# create Friend request

Tags: php, friend

In my application I'm trying to create an option to be friends. At this moment person X can send a request to person Z and I can put the data in sql. Person X = $_SESSION['name'] and person Z is $buddy['username'] (which I retrieve with my function GetUserById($user_id) )

Now, Person Z has to accept or to decline the request. I want to do it by showing 'Person X wants to be your friend', but I don't know how to pick the name 'Person X'? In first instance he was the $_SESSION['name'] but now person it is person Z.

Can I use a data-attribute on a button without ajax? Or can I do it otherwise?

Comment: Not sure that i understand completely... but do you store friend requests in separated db table? I would suggest it, so you can easily get sender/receiver data. Table scheme could be: id | sender_id | receiver_id | accepted | .... any additional data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a database table that stores: requester id, requestee id, status (pending, accepted, declined)

Then, when you want to show requests to Person Z, simply select all requester ids where: requestee id is equal to Person Z and status is pending.

In your case, it would give you Person X's id.

If you don't have ids, you can use usernames instead.

Comment: so sql statement: select * tblfriends where request_name = SESSION['name'] and status = pending fe?

Comment: If you're using username instead of user id, it could be something like this:
SELECT requester_name FROM requests WHERE requestee_name = $_SESSION['name'] AND status = 'pending'

Comment: that's what I mean... after that I have to just a for each to show it, right? fe 
if(isset POST['btn']) { foreach(friends as friend) {
friend['username]' . has send a friend request } }

Comment: Yes... so you can display each request a user has received